# how to run multiples queries with hidden div and multple conditions

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have multiple buttons for different tasks and after the task is completed successfully success/failure message it displayed on the hidden div.
it displays message for some time and then it disappears again.

Hidden div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showHide() {
            document.getElementById("hidden_div").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

sample forms:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Claim " id="btn" name="fbook" onclick="showHide()">
</form>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Claim " id="btn" name="twitter" onclick="showHide()">
</form>
```

php code

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['fbook'])) {
echo " facebook ";
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['twitter'])) {
echo " twitter ";
}
```

The problem:
when I click the first form button it displays the "facebook" , and then refreshes the page. when I click 2nd form button it displays again the same message 
"facebook" , and then refreshes the page. when I press again the 2nd button, it displays the correct message " twitter ".

What I need to achieve:

I have 10+ conditions for users to meet. and on each condition i want to award them bonuses, once the required queries are generated then the success or failure message 
is to be displayed on the hidden div.

Kindly suggest any other alternative way to accomplish the task.

If i am able to get rid of the form and use hyper link to achieve the task that would be more great.

updated code :

```
<div class="group">
<div class="echo" id="hidden_div" style="display:none ;width: 610px;height: 25px;border: 1px #e72727 solid;  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;border-radius: 10px;">
<?php
//Code for level 1 points
if(isset($_REQUEST['fbook'])) {
//sql queries goes here
echo " facebook ";
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['twitter'])) {
//sql queries goes here
echo " twitter ";
}
// and rest of the conditionss will also be written like this
//Code for level 3 points


?>
</div>
```

Comment: There Can Only Be One.... element id that is must be unique

Comment: @jaak kutt you mean to says i need to change id for each form to make it work

Comment: that was the reason why clicking the second button also got you to say "facebook"

Comment: @JaakKütt, this does not work , i changed the ids for each form but still same behavior.

Comment: please add more code where the hidden_div is also shown

Comment: @JaakKütt, I have updated  the question with more code for hidden div